# Chrome Tabs Extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, browser-tabs

I've tried a few of the Chrome tab extensions, but I've yet to find one that does what I want. This is something that one of my old FF extensions use to do. Help me out if you know a Chrome extensions that allows me to:

- Hold down control or alt and select a bunch of tabs and then
- Right click and give me the names/URLs of those tabs
- Or close those tabs
- Or move those tabs to a new window

Comment: -1 it'd help if you at least knew the name of that FF extension, or at least said why you can't tell us the name of it. Also your title should indicate that eg you are talking about operating on many tabs simultaneously, so not just a tab menu.

Answer (score -1):

[This](http://maketecheasier.com/10-chrome-extensions-for-efficient-tabs-management/2010/02/26) page has a list of ten chrome extensions that help you manage tabs in chrome. Have a look at them and see if they have this functionality.

Comment: I've look at many of those same extensions already. Haven't found one yet that does what I'm looking for.